# How to detect whether a sprite was touched

Tags: android, libgdx, screen, sprite

I use the following code to detect whether a sprite was touched:

```
Vector3 touchPoint=new Vector3();
MyGdxGame.camera.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(),0));

if (sprite1.getBoundingRectangle().contains(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y))
{

}
```

Unfortunately, "camera" is underlined red but I dont't know why. The error message is:

> Cannot resolve symbol ´camera´.

Could somebody help me to solve this problem, or is there a better way to detect whether a sprite was touched?

Camera in MyGdxGame.camera:

```
public OrthographicCamera camera;
public void create () {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 900,1600);
}
```

Comment: You need to spell it right, getBoundingRectangle

Comment: Oh what a mistake...

Comment: Do you know why camera is underlined red?

Comment: Can you show your code for `MyGdxGame`? Specifically, where you create the `MyGdxGame.camera` field?

Comment: I added the part in the question

Comment: I also added "static": public static OrthographicCamera camera; . Now it isn´t red underlined. Is it okay to turn OrthographicCamera to static?

Comment: I found the error